# Cypress wont pass the login page

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, cypress

We have a SAML2.0 and I am writing a test for the login page, but Cypress wont pass the test. The error I am receiving is:

> SecurityError: blocked from accessing a cross-origin frame.

How can I bypass this?

```
describe("Login", () => { 
    it("First Test", () => { 
        cy.visit("http://localhost:4200"); 
    });    
});
```

Comment: Cypress prevents you from visiting multiple domains in a test, this is by design. 
 See https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#One-Superdomain-per-Test for an explanation of this.  See https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/logging-in__single-sign-on for how to work with SSO

Comment: Please add snapshot or may be more details. I can try to write locally and see if something working solution